# Derivative of a complex function using difference quotient

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Given the complex-valued function $$\begin{align*}f: \mathbb C&\to \mathbb C\\z&\mapsto z\mathrm{Re}(z),\end{align*}$$ I want to find the points at which $f$ is differentiable using only the difference quotient, and compute the derivative at those points.

The derivative is $$f'(z)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{(z+h)\mathrm{Re}(z+h)-z\mathrm{Re}(z)}{h},$$ but how should I continue from here? More specifically, what does it mean for a complex-valued number like $h$ to tend to $0$ (unlike on the real axis, there are many ways to approach $0$) and how do I handle this when calculating a limit?

I have seen a trick using polar coordinates and simply letting $r$, a real number, tend to $0$, but I think this can only be used if I already know the point at which I want to calculate the derivative.

Comment: ${\bf Re}\, w=\dfrac12(w+\bar{w})$

Comment: If you write $h=re^{i\theta}$ with $r>0$ and $\theta\in\mathbb R$, then $h\to 0$ is equivalent to $r\to 0$. The limit will exist where the result is independent of the choice of $\theta$

Comment: @MPW Can you check my work on that one? I have $$\lim\limits_{r\to0}\frac{(z+re^{i\phi})\mathrm{Re}(z+re^{i\phi})-z\mathrm{Re}(z)}{re^{i\phi}}=\lim\limits_{r\to0}\mathrm{Re}(z)+z\cos\phi e^{-i\phi}+r\cos\phi\\=\mathrm{Re}(z)+z\cos\phi e^{-i\phi}=\mathrm{Re}(z)+\frac12z(1+e^{-2i\phi}).$$So if we want this to be independent of $\phi$, we need $z=0$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Mophotla : Looks perfect to me, good job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
f'(z)
&=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{(z+h){\bf Re}(z+h)-z{\bf Re}(z)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac12\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h(2z+h)+h\bar{z}+z\bar{h}+h\bar{h}}{h}\\
&=\dfrac12\lim_{h\to0}\left(2z+h+\bar{z}+\bar{h}+z\frac{\bar{h}}{h}\right)\\
&=z+\dfrac12\bar{z}+\dfrac12z\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\bar{h}}{h}
\end{align}
this limit exists only when $z=0$.